# How do I use JsTree with an exisiting Database and MVC 3?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, model, jstree

I am trying to create a hierarchical tree using an existing Database. I have looked through the JsTree documentation but I don't understand how to use it with an existing database. The documentation states that jsTree can take both html_data and Json_data but I don't understand how to retrieve the Json data or Html data with an existing database. All the tutorials I have found don't make any sense with an existing MS SQL DB. I need some help... bad, below I have included the model that I am working with. I just need some help with the view and controller, thanks for your help!

**Realistic Model**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DBFirstMVC.Models
{
    public partial class realistic
    {
        public string CAF_ID { get; set; }
        public string NDE_LEAD_DIRECTOR { get; set; }
        public string NDE_LEAD_MANAGER { get; set; }
        public string NDE_CC_DIRECTOR { get; set; }
        public string NDE_CC_MANAGER { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CC { get; set; }
        public string INVESTMENT_AREA { get; set; }
        public string MAJOR_PROGRAM { get; set; }
        public string DIVISION { get; set; }
        public string CLARITY_ID { get; set; }
        public string SPA { get; set; }
        public string PA { get; set; }
        public string PROJECT_NAME_ORIG { get; set; }
        public string PROJECT_NAME { get; set; }
        public string HIA { get; set; }
        public string HMP { get; set; }
        public string ERICSSON_IMPACT { get; set; }
        public string RESOURCE_MGR { get; set; }
        public string RESOURCE_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string RESOURCE { get; set; }
        public string PRIMARY_VENDOR { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CONFIDENCE_1Q { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CONFIDENCE_2Q { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CONFIDENCE_3Q { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CONFIDENCE_4Q { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ACCOUNTING_PERIOD { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> VALUE { get; set; }
        public int REALISTIC_PK { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The main columns that I need to work with are (in order of hierarchy) INVESTMENT_AREA, MAJOR_PROGRAM, PROJECT_NAME. I also need the INVESTMENT_AREA and MAJOR_PROGRAM to be distinct so we don't have repeats of existing areas or programs.

The goal of this site is so the managers can collapse or expand certain areas in a quick view. I thought that using jsTree would be the answer but if you have a better option I am all ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your existen model to JSON. 
The following links might help you.
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), [2](http://json.codeplex.com/), [3](http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/08/26/customizing-the-converter-for-json-net.aspx)